# Does Firebase Crash Reporter work only under installation from Google Play?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I want to add Firebase crash reporter to my Android project. I registered on the Firebase website and built my project.
I added Firebase in my Android project (and the JSON file too).

I also added permissions to Internet connection in:

```
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission
    android:name="ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    />
```

I added the test code in my simple test project:

```
private TextView mTextView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    try
    {
        mTextView.setText("Text");
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
    }


}
```

Then I tried to test the Firebase Android application in an actual device.

But Firebase Crash Reporting is not showing anything. Even after 24 hours, I didn't get any message from Firebase.

I suspect crash reporter doesn't work because I installed the application using the debugging tool of Android Studio, not from Google Play.

Does Firebase Crash Reporter work depending on the installation process (USB debugging or Google Play)?

============================================

Comprehensive discription of my mini test project.

1)It is my json file:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "484954907583",
    "firebase_url": "https://firstproj-88f01.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "firstproj-88f01",
    "storage_bucket": "firstproj-88f01.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:484954907583:android:a907cc6a5354ad1a",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.ff.crashrep1"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "484954907583-c3f2jv9eng4r4h6chlf33a6oc0s4hptl.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyDdlwnNGtv6RHo55xN7lxpuSrTh6MFss7k"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "484954907583-c3f2jv9eng4r4h6chlf33a6oc0s4hptl.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

2) My project settings in firebase console:

[image]

3) My simple activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        FirebaseCrash.log("Activity created");



        try {
            mTextView.setText("some text");
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception");
            FirebaseCrash.logcat(Log.ERROR, TAG, "NPE caught");
            FirebaseCrash.report(e);
        }


    }
}
```

4) My manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.ff.crashrep1">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

5) My project tree directories:

[image]

In the Json file field

"current_key": "AIzaSyDdlwnNGtv6RHo55xN7lxpuSrTh6MFss7k"

different from key in firebase console settings:

AIzaSyCGmjhNuovZQkQfmBKGcEj4KT4X9a0GFqo

I try to set both api keys in my project

AIzaSyDdlwnNGtv6RHo55xN7lxpuSrTh6MFss7k and AIzaSyCGmjhNuovZQkQfmBKGcEj4KT4X9a0GFqo

but it didn't help me.

I try set all thing but nothing help. I don't know why firebase dosn't 
react on my `FirebaseCrash.report` command.

I repeat, my android device registered in google. But I don't have my application in google play.

What did I do wrong in my project ?

Comment: If the JSON file you copied to app folder is correctly configured then it will show up in your firebase crash report section. Installation process (via google play or USB) doesn't matter.

Comment: @SrikarReddy, thank you for reply. My configuration of json file consist only in pasting package name of my project in special field in Firebase website and than Firebase auto-generated me json file. Does it need some additional settings for json file ?

Comment: Check through the crash reporting integration process again. Make sure the app's package name in the JSON file you downloaded is same as your current project name. Inside your JSON file, check the Firebase Url, project id, app id matches

Comment: Can you look at the log to see what shows up there?  Firebase Crash Reporting does depend on Google Play services.  Installing from USB shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: @SrikarReddy, thank you. I varify all settings but nothing help me. Could you check my test project, I add detailed description in my question report. Thanks for advance.

Comment: @DougStevenson, thanks for reply. I add detailed discription in my post, could you check my project, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing firebase crash report can works with both the case of USB debugging and install from play store.

So, First check whether your app generating exception or not otherwise it will not show You on firebase console.

And you dont need to change any key in your Json file ,keep that json file as it is downloaded from firebase console for the testing purpose.

You can test your app with this following code: Its working for my app

> ```
>  try
>         {
>             int a = 12/0;
>         }
>         catch(Exception e)
>         {
>               FirebaseCrash.report(new Exception("My first Android non-fatal error"+e));
>         }
> ```